# Parameter Passing for Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need help in fetching records using a stored procedure, where I need to pass a single parameter from the stored procedure, but I need to fetch both semester records

```
Declare @sem varchar(10)

set @sem ='1sem'
```

Ex: select * from student where TestType = '1sem'

```
set @sem ='2sem'
select * from student where TestType = '2sem'

set @sem ='dual'
```

If I need to select both 1st sem and 2 sem, I have only one parameter but how to handle it with the stored procedure.

```
Select * 
from student 
where TestType where?
```

How can I achieve

```
select * 
from student 
where TestType = '1sem' or TestType = '2sem'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to separate the testtype value with "," (comma)

then change your sql:

```
set @sem = '1sem, 2sem'
set @sql = 'select * from student where testype in ('+@sem+')'
execute sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
DECLARE @sem VARCHAR(10) = '1sem';
select * from student where testype = @sem OR (@sem = 'dual' AND testype IN '1sem','2sem');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare @sem as table and insert record

```
DECLARE @sem TABLE
(
    Testype VARCHAR(50),
)

INSERT INTO @sem
select Testype from student where TestType = '1sem' or TestType = '2sem'
```